# PyTube Request Gives 410 HTTP Response

Tags: python, pytube

it gives this error

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

But few days back it was working fine

I wanted to download a video from youtube

```py
from pytube import YouTube

# Define the YouTube video URL
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"

# Create a YouTube object and get the video streams
yt = YouTube(url)
mp4files = yt.streams
```

Comment: An alternative module is youtube_dl: [youtube_dl doc](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/).

Comment: youtube_dl gives the same error

Comment: I am not sure if this is a troll or not.

Comment: is it possible that youtube did some update that led to python not being able to download from it

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
yt = YouTube(url, use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
```

Comment: Could you share how you came up with this solution?